# How can we able to Find the Current Document is gone for printing from Print Queue?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, devexpress, c#-3.0

[image: P]Can u give a sample code for getting the Current Report is Get printed from Microsoft Visual Studio crystal Report/ from XtraReport?
if the Data is printed, when i check QuickPrint from the printPreview, i need a Message "the document is start printed" form the printer Queue/Printer Buffer.

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedTTOut != null)
        {

            Reports.XRTTout xrCompanyDetails = new Reports.XRTTout();
            xrCompanyDetails.Name = SelectedTTOut.TTOutCode;
            XtraReportPreviewModel model = new XtraReportPreviewModel(xrCompanyDetails);



            DocumentPreview preview = new DocumentPreview() { Model = model };
            DocumentPreviewWindow previewWindow = new DocumentPreviewWindow()
            {
                Content = preview
            };
            BarManagerCustomization.SetTemplate(preview, this.Resources["toolbarCustomization"] as DataTemplate);
            previewWindow.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
            previewWindow.ShowDialog();

        }
    }
```

Comment: You need some code to find out if a specific report is currently being printed?  Is this what you're asking?

Comment: If it is that also it is good for me, if u know this solution answer me. ( when i click print button it should go for printing, at tha time i need a conformation that the specific report is gone for printing/printed)

Comment: You will have to show me how you're doing your printing before I can tell you how to find out if the printing is completed.

Comment: i will put my code here. above... also i will put the image for ur help